# Get After current Array values with certain condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have some problem with my study case. I tried to match array values with column number in `table data`, while I was getting array values from`string`. So, the processing of the current value found is more than one in the column number will be appended after current array value, etc., if the current array value is found one matching in the column number process maybe finish, and last condition current array value not found in column number will be array value it. for more details, let's check this out

#### Table data

> no - number - c_num
>
> 1 - 1A2B - XXXX
>
> 2 - 1A2B 3C4D - YYYY
>
> 3 - 1A2B 3C4D 5E6F - ZZZZ

#### I will try it

```
<?php
$result = "";
$string = "1A2B 1A2B 3C4D 1A2B 1A2B 3C4D 1A2B 3C4D 5E6F 7G8H";
$array = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM WHERE number LIKE '$value%'";
  $exe = $connect->query($query);
  if($exe->num_rows > 1){
    //
    //do something?
    //
  } else if(empty($exe->num_rows)) {
    $result .= $value." ";
  } else {
    $row = $exe->fetch_array();
    $result .= $row['c_num']." ";
  } 
}
?>
```

#### Desired results

```
XXXX YYYY XXXX YYYY ZZZZ 7G8H
```

#### Explanation above

```
array(
  [XXXX] => 1A2B
  [YYYY] => 1A2B 3C4D
  [XXXX] => 1A2B
  [YYYY] => 1A2B 3C4D
  [ZZZZ] => 1A2B 3C4D 5E6F
  [7G8H] => 7G8H
);
```

Please give me a advice :)

Comment: If it returns more than one row, do it again with the value + the next one and so on until you have only one result

Comment: also do `$array = array_unique(explode(" ", $string));` to remove duplicates

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think you don't wanna remove duplicates in this case, they are important

Comment: @JulesR I agree with you, but I'm confused as to what kind of step sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to fetch all your db first into an array and create a "map" then traverse through it.

```
/* Query */
$result = array(
    array('number' => '1A2B', 'c_num' => 'XXXX'),
    array('number' => '1A2B 3C4D', 'c_num' => 'YYYY'),
    array('number' => '1A2B 3C4D 5E6F', 'c_num' => 'ZZZZ'),
);
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT number, c_num FROM table");

/* Create Map */
$map = array();

//while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
foreach($result as $row) {

    $numbers = explode(" ", $row['number']);
    $value = $row['c_num'];
    $count = count($numbers);

    $maps = array();
    create_map($maps, 0, $numbers, $count, $value);
    $map = array_merge_recursive($map, $maps);
}

function create_map(&$map, $i = 0, $numbers, $count, $value)
{
    $map = array($numbers[$i] => array());

    if ($i == $count-1)
        $map[$numbers[$i]]['value'] = $value;

    if ($i < $count-1) 
        create_map($map[$numbers[$i++]], $i, $numbers, $count, $value);
}

/* Search */
$string = "1A2B 1A2B 3C4D 1A2B 1A2B 3C4D 1A2B 3C4D 5E6F 7G8H";

$keys = explode(" ", $string);
$tmp_map = $map;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {

    $key = $keys[$i];
    $next_key = isset($keys[$i+1]) ? $keys[$i+1] : null;
    $tmp_map = &$tmp_map[$key];

    if (!isset($tmp_map[$next_key])) {
        //echo $key;
        echo isset($tmp_map['value']) ? $tmp_map['value'] : $key; echo " ";

        $tmp_map = $map;

    }
}
```

---

EDIT: if your search string is not that big, you can optimize by selecting records that contains number in search string.

```html
/* Query */

$search_string = "1A2B 1A2B 3C4D 1A2B 1A2B 3C4D 1A2B 3C4D 5E6F 7G8H";
$unique_ss = array_unique(explode(" ", $search_string));
$search_query = "number LIKE '". implode("*' OR number LIKE '", $unique_ss) . "*'";

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT number, c_num FROM table WHERE {$search_query}");

/* Create Map */
$map = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $numbers = explode(" ", $row['number']);
    $value = $row['c_num'];
    $count = count($numbers);

    $maps = array();
    create_map($maps, 0, $numbers, $count, $value);
    $map = array_merge_recursive($map, $maps);
}

function create_map(&$map, $i = 0, $numbers, $count, $value)
{
    $map = array($numbers[$i] => array());

    if ($i == $count-1)
        $map[$numbers[$i]]['value'] = $value;

    if ($i < $count-1) 
        create_map($map[$numbers[$i++]], $i, $numbers, $count, $value);
}

/* Search */

$keys = explode(" ", $search_string);
$tmp_map = $map;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {

    $key = $keys[$i];
    $next_key = isset($keys[$i+1]) ? $keys[$i+1] : null;
    $tmp_map = &$tmp_map[$key];

    if (!isset($tmp_map[$next_key])) {
        //echo $key;
        echo isset($tmp_map['value']) ? $tmp_map['value'] : $key; echo " ";

        $tmp_map = $map;

    }
}
```

Comment: too many knowledge for me, thanks, sir.
But, I have many rows at least 100K in the database, and then to long wait response to my browser. Always fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. I tried to fix with change max_execution_time = 0 (before 30) on php.ini and i think to must create a file like json? every `fetch_array()` from database? or any solution sir?

Comment: @Luckyman you can minimize the selection of records by filtering it with numbers that are present in the search string.

Please see edited version for the full implementation.

Also use, mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: OMG, I don't think about it sir .. thank you!! Good luck back to you :)